# Iptables WiFi , blocking

Tags: wireless-networking, iptables, blocking

I would like to block all Wi-Fi devices except one. I have two Wi-Fi routers and I am only allowing one in my IPTABLES rules to connect; but I am able to still connect to both.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Wi-Fi MAC I want

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 40:16:7e:a3:ae:fc -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 40:16:7e:a3:ae:f8 -j ACCEPT
```

WLAN0 MAC

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 00:22:fa:cc:ff:34 -j ACCEPT
```

Wi-Fi MAC I want to block

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 04:A1:51:2C:DD:F6 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 40:16:7e:a3:ae:fc -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 40:16:7e:a3:ae:f8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 00:22:fa:cc:ff:34 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j DROP
```